# Inhomogeneous Cauchy-Euler equation: $x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)-y(x)=x$ for $x>0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this DE (for $x>0$) by a substitution $x=e^t$:

$$x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)-y(x)=x \implies \color{blue}{e^{2t}y''(e^t)+e^ty'(e^t)}-\color{green}{y(e^t)}=e^t$$

Let $z(t)=y(x)$ and let $x=e^t \implies \color{green}{z(t)}= y(e^t)$

By the chain rule we get:

$z'(t)=y'(e^t)e^t$

$\color{blue}{z''(t)}=y''(e^t)e^{2t}+y'(e^t)e^{t}$

The green and blue part can be substituted into the equation and I get:

$$z''(t)-z(t)=e^t$$

The solution to the homogeneous equation $z''-z=0$ is:

$$z_h(t)=c_1 e^t+c_2e^{-t}$$

By choosing a suitible "ansatz" $z_s(t)=Ate^t$, I get the special solution to the inhomogeneous equation $z''-z=e^t$:

$$z_s(t)=\frac{1}{2}te^t$$

Therefore the general solution to the inhomogeneous equation is:

$$z(t)=c_1 e^t+c_2e^{-t}+\frac{1}{2}te^t$$

Because I made the substitution $x=e^t$ I need to substitute $t=\ln{x}$

$$\implies y(x)=c_1e^{\ln{x}}+c_2e^{-\ln{x}}+\frac{1}{2}(\ln{x})e^{\ln{x}}\\=c_1 x+\frac{c_2}{x}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}x\ln{x}}$$

**Here is my problem:** The red part $\frac{1}{2}x\ln{x}$ doesn't solve the differential equation and I am not sure where I have gone wrong. Wolfram alpha also gives me the same (real) solution the homogeneous equation but the general solution looks like this:

[image]

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: There's probably a solution of the form $y=x^\alpha$

Comment: Your solution looks correct to me

Comment: Your solution solves the ODE. I didn't check the Wolfram alpha's solution but maybe there is something to do with coefficient changing.

Comment: @AnJin Thanks for your reply. I made a mistake checking my solution. My solution does actually solve it so all works out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2y''(x)+xy'(x)-y(x)=x$$
$$x^2y''(x)+2xy'(x)-(xy'+y(x))=x$$
$$(x^2y')'-(xy)'=x$$
Integrate:
$$x^2y'-xy=\frac {x^2}2+c_1$$
$$\frac {xy'-y}{x^2}=\frac 1 {2x}+\frac {c_1}{x^3}$$
Integrate
$$\frac {y}{x}=\frac 1 {2} \ln x -\frac {c_1}{2x^2}+c_2$$
$$ \boxed { {y(x)}=\frac 1 {2}x \ln x +\frac {c_1}{x}+c_2x}$$
Your answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @qmd yw... .....

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the logic of Wolfram alpha, but both the solutions are same if you take constants $c_{1}=c_{1}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{ic_{2}}{2}$ and $c_{2}=c_{1}-\frac{ic_{2}}{2}$

Comment: Maple return your correct answer